# List of magento 2 soap functions

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap

I have worked in magento 1x soap. Now I am writing for magento 2. I can find from [reference guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/soap/bk-soap.html#list-of-service-names-per-module) the service list with endpoints. But I am having trouble finding out the functions in those service lists. Also, what parameters are to be sent to those services seems not to be documented anywhere.

Does anybody know how to get list of functions with documented input and output sample response. The REST [swagger](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) is very detailed in what parameters are to be sent to which function and what response you will get.

Is there a similar documentation page for SOAP services as well.